# Сгрупировать файлы в папки по дате

Tags: powershell

Есть каталог с большим количеством файлов.
Необходимо создать папки по годам изменения файлов и переместить файлы в папку с годом его изменения.
Т.е. если есть файлы только 2019, 2018, 2017 года, то должно быть 3 каталога и в каждом файлы только данного года изменения.
 Создание папок примерно выглядит так, но не работает

```
Get-ChildItem $path | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$path\($_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyy'))"
```

или так?

```
Get-ChildItem $path | % { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path ($new = [string]$path+[string]$_LastWriteTime.Year)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object {
    $newPath = "$path\$($_.LastWriteTime.Year)\$($_.Name)"
    New-Item -Path $newPath -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null
    Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но при выполнении Вашего кода у меня Type: file
Move-Item : Не удается найти путь ..., так как он не существует.
...1:9 знак:5
+     Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\work\ps\tc_remove\DSC_0510.JPG:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
 
Type:

Comment: а папка с годом создалась?

Comment: При выполнении у меня пишет Type: и моргает курсор. Я ввожу file. Создается 1 папка, хотя файлы разных годов, в нем создается пустой файл с правильным именем того же года. И затем выдает ошибку выше.

Comment: Я закинул скрипт в каталог с файлами, сейчас он правильно отрабатывает, но нужно каждый раз писать file. Это можно убрать?

Comment: Странно, а переменная $path у вас определена?

Comment: Да, конечно. Все я допилил. Окончательный вариант у меня выглядит так

`Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object {
    $newPath = "$pathf\$($_.LastWriteTime.Year)\$($_.Name)"
    New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path $newPath -Force | Out-Null
    Move-Item $_ -Destination $newPath -Force
}`

Comment: @pvk Понял. В меня оно не спрашивало параметр `ItemType` для `NewItem`. В меня павершел 5.1